# Tables names with capitals use _

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I just created a model called GrupoInstructor, the table's name is grupoinstructor
When I want to create a query for that model it shows "base table grupo_instructors doesn't exist". Why is that? why laravel adds a _ to the table's name?

Is there a way to tell lavarel that my table's name  is grupoinstructor? I just realized that have some errors in my previous migrations so my last one doesn't rollback...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your model you can override the name of your table to suit your needs

```
protected $table = 'grupoinstructor';
```

Laravel and most of the frameworks assume that capital letters are used for separation hence the reason why it expects your table name to be called `grupo_instructor` which in my mind is more readable way anyway instead of concatenating the words together.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the answer. About my problems with migrations. I just reallize that cannot rollback. When I try so it gives me an error, about a migration that I use like 6 migrations "ago", I have been creating another migrations with no error messages I even rolled back like 3 migrations back... Is there a way to reset and start from the last migration and  roll back just the las one or two... If that's not possible I have a big problem here...

Comment: you should fix your migration `down` methods for successful rollbacks. 
There is an option to start with a fresh database, but you will lose your existing data. 
You can open another question with your migrations and errors that you get so the people in the community can help.

Comment: Thanks your help is appreciated.